# Rails Rake task displayed execution expired message and program stopped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, paperclip

I have a rake task to load car's image from the table websites using paperclip. The image stored in database as a remote link.

Here is my code and i'm using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.8 and DB mysql.

```
namespace :db do

  task :load_photo  => :environment do
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'net/http'
  require 'paperclip'
  begin
  images =Website.find(:all,:conditions=>["image_url is not null"])
  images.each do |photo|
     url = URI.parse(photo.image_url)
     Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
         if http.head(url.request_uri).code == "200"
           Car.update_attribute(:photo,open(url))
         end
     end
  end
  rescue Exception => e
  end
 end 
 end
```

Run above rake task by db:load_photo. In my table (Website) has 60,000 rows. Rake task running upto 10000 rows only and execution terminated with an error message **"execution expired"**.

Can any one help me to figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to play with `read_timeout` http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M001372

Comment: Can you show the output of rake db:load_photo --trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it more performant to run it in batches, active record has a `find_in_batches` method which stops loading all the records into memory at one time.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/23/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-batched-find

You could change your code to look like:

```
namespace :db do
  task :load_photo  => :environment do
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'net/http'
    require 'paperclip'
    Website.find_in_batches(:conditions=>["image_url is not null"]) do |websites|
      websites.each do |website|
        begin
          url = URI.parse(website.image_url)
          Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
            if http.head(url.request_uri).code == "200"
              Car.update_attribute(:photo,open(url))
            end
          end
        rescue Exception => e
        end
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Hi andrew, can you help me to fix rake aborted!,
undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x4df19d8> Thanks!

Comment: I've fixed the rake task to work for rails 2.3.x now, there where method is part of rails 3, it should work now

Comment: Hi Andrew, seems that above code executed for all records. But in log shows "Error = Too many links - /var/www/rails/public/images/photos/32123". Any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew, rake task executed, but when parsed some of remote URL i got Too many links error, but any way the above rake code execution takes 2 days to complete for 60,000 records. any idea?

Comment: The problem with "too many links" appears to be that paperclip is trying to put too many photos in a single directory (it looks like you've reached 32123 directories in /var/www/rails/public/images/photos), add something like `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = 
"/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension" 
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = 
":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basenam e.:extension" ` to your paperclip config

Comment: Problem fixed. can you suggestion me how to reduce the time of execution( Taking 2 days to complete for 80,000 records). Thank you so much Andrew!

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, but it looks like you're making a little DoS attack to the server you're pulling images from.

You can try to play with a little delay between sequential requests (like "sleep 1").

Also, if your "execution expired" is a Timeout::Error exception, then you can't catch it with

```
rescue Exception => e
```

because Timeout::Error is not a subclass of StandardError, it is a subclass of the Interrupt class.  You have to catch it explicitly, like so:

```
rescue Timeout::Error => e
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, i'am also tried with Timeout::Error exception handling but still rake task gets expired or SIGNUP message displayed. Help me Thanks!

Comment: You can also try "rescue" without arguments - that would catch exceptions of any type. Also, is it always *exactly* 10000 rows before termination?

Comment: Did you tried to add delay after each request? I'm still thinking the problem is that the server becomes overloaded with your requests. If "sleep 1" after each request is too slow, you could combine it with "find_in_batches" advice from Andrew Nesbitt.